# Angular - Simple function

Tags: javascript, angular

I had a previous code like this:

Basically I added the active status to the li docker logs and open the sub-menu of Docker.

html

```
<li id="dockerMenu">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#docker-pages" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="testing-main.webapp.pages">
            <img src="../resources/img/icons/docker-icon.png" alt="" class="menuIcon">
            <span class="menu-title">Docker <i class="fa fa-sort-down"></i></span>
        </a>
        <div class="collapse" id="docker-pages">
            <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu" data-simplebar>
                <security:authorize access="hasAuthority('Administrator')">
                <li class="nav-item" id="docker-status">
                    <a href="/docker-status">
                        <img src="../resources/img/icons/status.png" alt="">
                        <span class="menu-title">Container Status</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                ...
               <ul>
           <div>
              </li>

 var url = window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
 if(url === "/docker-logs") {
    $('#docker-logs').addClass('active');
    $('#dockerMenu a').click();
}
```

I wanted to do the same on Angular but I don't know how

```
 ngOnInit() {

this.toggleMenus();
}
toggleMenus() {
    let url = window.location.pathname;
    console.log(url);
    switch(url) {
      case "/docker-logs":
        //how do I activate this?
    }
```

Comment: this should be easy, right?

Comment: any help please?

Comment: If you want to use a Framework you should use tools that provide `routerModule` : [Doc](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule).